# Symfony Dependency injection to class

Tags: symfony

I have a class in App\Util which needs the MailerInterface Dependency. So I added it directly to the constructor like this:

```
public function __construct(MailerInterface $mailer)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
    }
```

Then I added the argument in the services.yaml:

```
services: 
        ...
        App\Util\OwnerMailValidation:
              arguments: ['@mailer']
```

In the end I used exactly the same code as provided by the symfony [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/injection_types.html) but I keep getting the error:
`Too few arguments to function App\Util\OwnerMailValidation::__construct(), 0 passed [...] 1 expected`

My complete servicey.yaml:

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      
        autoconfigure: true

    App\:
        resource: '../src/'
        exclude:
            - '../src/DependencyInjection/'
            - '../src/Entity/'
            - '../src/Kernel.php'
            - '../src/Tests/'

    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller/'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    App\Util\OwnerMailValidation:
        class: App\Util\OwnerMailValidation
        arguments: ['@mailer']
```

Comment: Which version of symfony are you using? Could you provide the autowiring part of your services.yaml file please. Something like `App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests}'`

Comment: I am using Symfony v4.22.0. I added the service.yaml to the thread (but I did not change anything there yet (besided the new OwnerMailValidation etry) @Mcsky

Comment: You probably don't need the service configuration lines in your services.yaml file at all.  Autowire will take care of it.  I suspect that you are new'ing your OwnerMailValidation class instead of injecting it.  The PHP new operator knows nothing about the Symfony DI container.

Comment: @Cerad that's what I thought it would do, but it gives me the same error again.

Comment: Read the rest of my original comment.  Are you doing $x = new OwnerMailValidation()? If not, then update your question and show how the service is being injected.  I suppose you could also try the ever popular clearing of the cache.

Comment: Sorry @Cerad, I am doing $util = new OwnerMailValidation()

Comment: And like I said in my original comment, the new operator has no knowledge of the Symfony Dependency Injection container.  Using new will simply will not work.  This is actually a fairly common misconception.  Go back to the basics and read the docs on the service container.  Maybe create a new test project and add a few services following the examples until you understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a single implementation of MailerInterface you shouldn't write anything in your service.yaml
Symfony can figure it out on his own.
If it still doesn't work try to do this

```
App\Util\OwnerMailValidation:
    arguments:
      $mailer: '@<the class that implements MailerInteface that you want to inject>'
```

As @cerad said autowiring works if you inject your class into another.
If you're doing `$validation = new OwnerMailValidation();` it just won't work because it requires a MailerInterface in the constructor.
You should inject your OwnerMailValidation into the controller method or into the class constructor.

Comment: Just for info, if it was an argument related problem then the error message would be significantly different.

Answer (score 0):

Try this config:

```
services: 
        ...
        App\Util\OwnerMailValidation:
           class: App\Util\OwnerMailValidation
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added the class but it does not change anything. I keep getting the same error

Comment: @nikserg - Just for info, if class is omitted then the service id is assumed to be the fully qualified class name.  It is all in the docs.